# How to get weather forecast at device location using latitude and longitude with GPS only

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to get weather forecast or information (temperature, humidity, air pressure, etc) at device location (lat, long) using GPS only (without internet connection) ? If yes, can anyone here guide me?

Comment: You would need special sensors in your phone for that. I think some phopnes have sensors for air pressure, but definetly not temperature, as the phone generates it itself.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get weather forecast or information (temperature, humidity, air pressure, etc) at device location (lat, long) using GPS only (without internet connection) ?

No.